# Group several items using rectangles with rounded corners

Tags: inkscape

After trying for an hour now, and again realizing that inkscape is incredibly powerful, but also second least intuitive to use, please someone help ...

I attached the picture of what I want to do:
 [image: Several items grouped with rectangle-like border]
What I can do so far:

- Make an empty rectangle
- Change color and make the line dashed (way too many points, too close points so far)

PS: You might already have deduced from the example what level of skill we are dealing with here. Also, how do I put in a new line after the picture?

Comment: Welcome on GD, Maxim. If you want to draw the dashed line, you could simply draw two rectangles with [round corners](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Shapes-Rectangles.html), make them overlap, use Ctrl and + to create an [union](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html) of the paths, change the [border stroke](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/basic/tutorial-basic.html) and remove the fill. To align the boxes you can use [snapping](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html) or [alignment](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Align.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just had a colleague come over and we together with google we came up with the same answer! I will copy yours, so that the question is answered.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I guess the OP would accept that if you were to make it into an answer. For the time being, I added your content to their own.

Comment: @MaximMoloshenko: feel free to write a complete answer based on my indications but with your own images, it could be an interesting exercise.

Answer (score -1):

See Paolo Gibellinis comment - the links he provided are really helpful for noobs like myself!

For completeness: If you want to draw the dashed line, you could simply draw two rectangles with [round corners](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Shapes-Rectangles.html), make them overlap, use Ctrl and + to create an [union](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html) of the paths, change the [border stroke](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/basic/tutorial-basic.html) and remove the fill. To align the boxes you can use [snapping](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html) or [alignment](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Align.html).